# How to test method channel that call from native to Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm developing a native plugin and trying to do unit tests.
All unit tests will be done in Dart (No native code).

Flutter has a test example of how you can test call method channel from Dart to native using `setMockMethodCallHandler`.

The problem is I've not found the way to test method channel that calls from native to Dart that uses `setMethodCallHandler` to handle a call from native.

Here is an example

```
// main.dart

class Plugin {

  static MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('plugin');
 
  Plugin() {
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      print("called from native: ${call.method}");
    });
  }

}
```

```
// tests/main_test.dart

void main() {
  const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('core.super_router');
  Plugin plugin;

  setUp(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    plugin = Plugin();
  });

  test("call from native", () async {
    _channel.invokeMethod("something");
    // This call can't reach the handler in the Plugin
    // And there is no method like mockInvokeMethod
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No but I have already file the feature request.

Comment: @Limbou You can follow up here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63465

Comment: I think I found a solution to that problem. Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-platform-channels-ce7f540a104e

Take a look at chapter: "Don’t mock platform channels".

Also, take a look here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38954

With these two links I managed to mock methods called from native to dart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snippet below based on 
[CyrilHu's](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63465#issuecomment-899379305) approach, works perfect for me.

```
test("Listening device", () async {

    ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger.handlePlatformMessage(
    'channnelName',
    StandardMethodCodec().encodeMethodCall(
        MethodCall('methodName', '{"result":true}')),(ByteData data){});

     ...
});
```